# Joint probabilities with triples

Tags: probability

Suppose

$$    \mu_{12},
      \mu_{13},
      \mu_{23}$$

are three probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$
  satisfying:

the marginal distribution of $\mu_{1}$
  obtained from $\mu_{12}$
  coincides with the marginal obtained from $\mu_{13}$,
  and similarly for $\mu_{2}$
  and $\mu_{3}$.

I need to find an example such that this holds, but for which there is no triple $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ satisfying:

$$\mu_{ij}$$

is the distribution of

$$(X_{i},X_{j}) 
\text{ for } i\neq j$$

Comment: I've been playing around looking at different conditional dependencies.  I don't think there is an example if two of the X_i  are conditionally independent given the third.

Answer (score 1):

Try $\mu_{12}=\mu_{23}=\mu_{31}=\frac12\delta_{(0,1)}+\frac12\delta_{(1,0)}$.

Then $\mu_{1}=\mu_{2}=\mu_{3}=\frac12\delta_{0}+\frac12\delta_{1}$ but no triple $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ can exist since the marginals impose that $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is in $S$ almost surely, where the set $S=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\{0,1\}^3\mid x_1+x_2=x_2+x_3=x_3+x_1=1\}$ is empty.